# What's the best architecture to run scheduled jobs (max. every hour) and jobs initiated by users, both of which do same processing?

Tags: architecture, enterprise-architecture, scheduling

I own a library that reads a file (large or small) and converts it to a special format that one of our vendor's application needs. This conversion can take anywhere between 5 seconds to 10 minutes depending on the file size.

Until now, when my users wanted to use this capability, they needed to integrate my library into their application. However, I want to offer this capability of my library as a service, so users can send a request with parameters for the special file creation based on a file that exists in my server's filesystem (ex: S3). I plan to provide both API integration and a frontend where users can do the configurations and send a request.

There are 2 ways my end users will use my service:

1. Upload the original file to my server, and request special file creation. I plan to simply take user's file from my UI and upload it to the shared filesystem.
2. Schedule special file creation. There are some source files that I will be downloading regularly from external vendors, and my users need special file creation from these files. So they will just select which of these files they need the special file for, and I need to make that special file available to them on a daily basis (stored in shared filesystem, downloadable from UI).

What's the best way to offer this capability? Here are my constraints:

1. Solution must be able to run in any public cloud (AWS/GCP/Azure) without too much customizations. I plan to containerize my solution component (create a docker image) that I should be able to deploy anywhere.
2. Solution must be scalable - we expect numerous small file conversion requests per minute (say 10), and also numerous scheduled file conversion requests (100/day). The scheduled file conversions must finish within an hour.
3. Ideally, both scheduled and ad-hoc special file creation should happen in the same component.
4. Again, ideally, I would need to maintain just one docker image for al public clouds (AWS/GCP/Azure) for my solution since my company plans to provide this solution as both SaaS and on-prem deployment to other companies (B2B).

In my opinion, I should create a pool of instances that do special file creation in async mode. When user submits a request, I set status as queued in DB, return response, and spawn a separate thread in my server that works on:

1. Downloading the source file from the shared file system, and updating status at start and end.
2. Converting it, and updating status at start and end.
3. Uploading the result to shared filesystem, and updating status at start and end.

If the user wishes to see the status of a job, the UI will simply query the DB for the status (and other details).

This pool of instances should be behind a load balancer so requests come to machines that aren't heavily utilized. Furthermore, I should run a batch on an hourly basis that checks a database on which files need to be converted on a scheduled basis for that hour, and sends request for them to the same pool of instances that I will use for special file creation.

Other options:

1. Use a high frequency batch to check for any file conversion requests. I'm not sure how scalable this is, and even if I have a pool of batch applications, I will have to write job allocation from scratch - which is something I don't want to do since that problem has already been solved by other technologies. A batch will also limit user's capability to create the special files since they will need to wait for a minimum amount of time before their "job" is done.
2. Use pub/sub model. The drawback for this is that I would need to maintain different docker images for different public cloud providers since they have different offerings for pub/sub model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> we expect numerous small file conversion requests per minute (say 10), and also numerous scheduled file conversion requests (100/day)

I wouldn't call 10/min or 100/day numerous by any stretch of the imagination.

> The scheduled file conversions must finish within an hour.

Given you said it can take up to 10 min to generate a file, at worst you can do 6 files in a given hours, assuming one concurrent thread. If it's 5 seconds, then you can do about 720 files in an hour, still assuming one concurrent thread.

Whether you need concurrent conversion or not depends on how often the *average* file takes, and how strict you need to keep to your one hour limit.

> 3. Ideally, both scheduled and ad-hoc special file creation should happen in the same component.

To a web api, all requests look the same. So it's not very hard to make it so that you have a public API endpoint which is called by end users and scheduled jobs alike. The process is exactly the same, so there's no issue here in needing to serve these two consumers differently.

Since you talk about taking up to 10 minutes to generate this file, you'd want to move to a job-based API. I.e. the first request returns a job reference, and then the consumer can poll for that job's completion. Essentially:

```
 CLIENT (request)                  SERVER (response)
--------------------------------------------------------------
 Generate this file for me!        Okay, this is called job 5
 Is job 5 done?                    Nope.
 Is job 5 done?                    Nope.
 Is job 5 done?                    Nope.
 Is job 5 done?                    Nope.
 Is job 5 done?                    Yup.
 Give me the job 5 result!         Here you go!
```

For the scheduled jobs, this is fairly straightforward to implement, i.e. "poll until Yup, then fetch".

For the frontend, you can choose to either have a loading spinner while checking completion in the background, or list it as a side job (the way Azure handles its resource creation jobs, i.e. in a side panel while you continue to use the site itself).

It's not impossible to use callback or pub/sub for this, but I don't think it's worth it. You're not going to have a sequence of messages being sent, or a long-term communication channel. It's one job with one result, so job-ID-based polling seems more appropriate here to not overly complicate your setup.

The scheduled jobs then run in a process of their own, which in turn fires off requests to your API, gets the job ID, and repeatedly checks for the job to have been completed. I lack GCP/AWS knowledge, but I would assume that these platforms have some native solution for scheduled jobs, much like Azure Scheduler.

I am unaware of any common scheduling language or open standard that is innately compatible with any cloud provider (other than just running your own VM with does it for you, which is a relative waste of resources/budget).

> I plan to provide both API integration and a frontend where users can do the configurations and send a request.

In order to not have to develop two APIs, I suggest building your frontend so that it utilizes the same API integration. This saves you from having to build two endpoints (one REST, one returning a view).

> This pool of instances should be behind a load balancer so requests come to machines that aren't heavily utilized.

Once you have a single public API that serves both use cases, that API can be made scalable however your preferred cloud provider has made scalability available to you. The scheduled jobs themselves won't take on the brunt of the workload, they simply intermittenly check to see if the API has done its job.

This also means that you can decide how many concurrent conversions you want to run. Don't want to run an extra concurrent conversion? Don't return a job reference to the caller (and a non-200 status code, preferably 429). That limit depends on your needs and the cost of running multiple conversions (i.e. cloud provider cost based on specs), I can't make that call for you.

If you want to stick to the limit of doing a scheduled job of 100 file conversions which could each take 10 minutes, and finish it in no longer than 60 minutes, that means you're going to be needing just under 17 concurrent threads to achieve that goal.
Mathematically, each thread gives you 1 file per 10 min, so 6 per hour, so 17 threads give you 102 files per hour.

Comment: I see. so divide the problem into two - scheduling and running the file conversion logic. So just to clarify, what would be the best place to run the file conversion job? Should it be on an application running on an instance (for ex: EC2) in a pool of instances?

Comment: @user1162657: I have no experience with what I presume is AWS?

Comment: Yes. I wanted to check if this would be the right way - create an application that performs file conversion, and deploy it on a set of VMs which have access to the shared file system. The application can accept requests for file conversion.

Comment: @user1162657: Sounds about right, yes.